# GPU allocation within a SBATCH

Tags: slurm

I have access to a large GPU cluster (20+ nodes, 8 GPUs per node) and I want to launch a task several times on `n` GPUs (1 per GPU, `n` > 8) within one single batch without booking full nodes with the `--exclusive` flag.

I managed to pre-allocate the resources (see below), but I struggle very hard with launching the task several times within the job. Specifically, my log shows no value for the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES variable.

I know how to do this operation on fully booked nodes with the `--nodes` and `--gres` flags. In this situation, I use `--nodes=1` `--gres=gpu:1` for each `srun`. However, this solution does not work for the present question, the job hangs indefinitely.

In the MWE below, I have a job asking for 16 gpus (`--ntasks` and `--gpus-per-task`). The jobs is composed of 28 tasks which are launched with the `srun` command.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH --job-name=somename
#SBATCH --partition=gpu
#SBATCH --nodes=1-10
#SBATCH --ntasks=16
#SBATCH --gpus-per-task=1

for i in {1..28}
do
        srun echo $(hostname) $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES &
done

wait
```

The output of this script should look like this:

```
nodeA 1
nodeR 2
...
```

However, this is what I got:

```
nodeA
nodeR
...
```

Comment: Which version of Slurm is that?

Comment: It's slurm 18.08.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
srun echo $(hostname) $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES &
```

the expansion of the `$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` variable will be performed on the master node of the allocation (where the script is run) rather than on the node targeted by `srun`. You should escape the `$`:

```
srun echo $(hostname) \$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES &
```

By the way, the `--gpus-per-task=` appeared in the `sbatch` manpage in the 19.05 version. When you use it with an earlier option, I am not sure how it goes.

Comment: I think it's because I have the wrong version of slurm.